# Google chart - All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm having a problem regarding a google chart, with one string it works, if i want to put two strings it doesn't. My code

```
$results=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
        array('label' => 'Escola', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Dominios', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Total', 'type' => 'number')
    );
    $rows = array();
    foreach($results as $r){
        $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' => $r['escola']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => $r['dominio']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['total']);
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;
```

and my chart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], 'language': 'pt'});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() {
    var jsonData = null;
    var json = $.ajax({
        url: "xxxxxx.php", // make this url point to the data file
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: (
            function(data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
                var options = {
                    'legend':'center',
                    'title':'Domínios',
                    'width':800,
                    'height':600,
                    colors: ['#e2431e']
                }
                var chart= new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
                draw(data, options);
            })
    }).responseText;
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

I'm receiving that error each time  the chart is drawed but i don't see where the error is

any help?

Comment: does this question need to have highcharts as a tag?

Comment: see the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#data-format) for a `ColumnChart` -- the first column can be string, the rest should be numbers. if you don't want the second string in the chart but still want it in the data, use a DataView to [hide the column](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_hideColumns) before drawing...